# В сафари не работает linear-gradient для тектса

Tags: html, css, linear-gradient

Вот HTML

```
<h2>Компании, <span>которым<br> помогли</span> найти офис</h2>
```

Вот CSS

```
h2 span {
    background: #86C446;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom right, #86C446 0%, #05ADE4 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom right, #86C446 0%, #05ADE4 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #86C446 0%, #05ADE4 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На айфоне в сафари не отображается весь текст. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет

```
display: inline-block;
```

Только при том, что у тебя судя по скриншоту надо `inline`, придётся оборачивать слова отдельно и делать два разных градиента.